# what strategy to consider when moving from oracle to cassandra

Tags: oracle, nosql, migration, cassandra

We are thinking of moving from Oracle database to Cassandra. Is a there a step by step techniques to design Cassandra tables based on what we have in Oracle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look some slides by Patrick McFadin about modeling techniques, it should definitely help :

[**The Datamodel is dead, long live the data model**](http://fr.slideshare.net/patrickmcfadin/the-data-model-is-dead-long-live-the-data-model)

[**Become a super modeler**](http://fr.slideshare.net/patrickmcfadin/become-a-super-modeler)

[**The world' next top data model**](http://fr.slideshare.net/patrickmcfadin/the-worlds-next-top-data-model)